# Subscribing to an event of a class that holds the override method of the class you reference

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am working with background workers to update a progress bar in a WPF UI I am working on. This background worker is getting its progress updates from multiple events that I am subscribed to, because the progress bar goes through several loading stages, and the percentages for those come from several places. here is some example/pseudo code explaining what I mean

The `DoWork` method of my background worker and the methods I am using to currently get some progress updates

```
// These are working fine
private void BwOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
{
    orderProcessing.OnOrderProgress += OrderStatus;
    orderProcessing.OnStandardOrderProgress += StandardOrderStatus;
    orderProcessing.CreateOrders(orders); 
}

private void OrderStatus(int currentCount, int totalItems, string Message)
{
   if (totalItems > 0)
     bw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(((double)currentCount / (double)totalItems) * 100),
                        Message);
}

private void StandardOrderStatus(int currentCount, int totalItems, string Message)
{
   if (totalItems > 0)
      bw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(((double)currentCount / (double)totalItems) * 100),
                        Message);
}
```

Some code from my order processing class

```
public abstract class OrderProcessing
{
   public delegate void OrderProgress(int CurrentItems, int TotalItems, string Message);
   public event MasterSalesOrder.StandardOrderProgress OnStandardOrderProgress;
   public event OrderProgress OnOrderProgress;

   public abstract List<MasterSalesOrder> CreateOrders(List<Order> orders);
}
```

Some code from the class that holds the override method for CreateOrders()

```
public abstract class OrderProcessingFile : OrderProcessing
{
    public event OrderProgress OnOrderProgress;

    public override List<MasterSalesOrder> CreateOrders(List<Order> orders)
    {
        //Does Some Stuff

        foreach(var stuff in stuffs)
        {  
          OnOrderProgress(currentCount, totalCount, "Message");

        }
    }
}
```

Since I am clearly not explaining this well,  I need to get info from the OrderProcessingFiles OnOrderProgress event via the OrderProcessing class that I create in the DoWork method.I am unsure on how to subscribe to an event when my code never directly instantiates an instance of the `OrderProcessingFile` class and it is never directly referred to.

I have tried looking for answers but as my title will show I am having a hard time even wording this in a way to get useful results, and I am genuinely stuck on this one. Let me know if more detail is needed, I tried to strip down my code to only the relevant parts but I feel like I'm explaining this strangely.

Comment: Why do you need multiple events?  Why not just a single event given they use the same signature?  Then your derived class could just use this.  As an aside, `BackgroundWorker` is a bit old hat - I'd suggest looking at TPL (`Task`), `async`/`await` and `IProgress<T>`.

Comment: @charlesmager are you referring to OrderStatus and StandardOrderStatus?

Comment: Yes.  Then you could raise this single event from within `CreateOrders`.  I may have the wrong end of the stick, however, as it's quite unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @charlesmager ok give me a couple minutes and I'll strip this down some more, I think some of my code is distracting from the real issue

Comment: @CharlesMager OK I stripped it down a lot, let me know if this makes more sense

Comment: It's event less clear now - there are no events.  Your comment says you need to get progress updates from this event - it isn't an event, it's a method.  What do you want to subscribe to and where and what is stopping you doing this?  And do you mean subscribe, or raise?  Before the edit, I assumed you meant raise as subscribe made no sense in the context.

Comment: @CharlesMager Ok I rolled back the update and added some stuff in the OrderProcessingFile class. I need to get info from the OrderProcessingFiles OnOrderProgress event via the OrderProcessing class that I create in the DoWork method. Sorry Ive been so confusing, its been a log day and I think my brain is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized what it is I was really trying to do and have thus found an answer. Using the method found in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx) MSDN article I have implemented the follow code:

This is my UI

```
  private void BwOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        orderProcessing.OnOrderProgress += OrderStatus;
        orderProcessing.CreateOrders(FanGlobal.BrandItems, FanGlobal.BrandItemMasterCustomers);
    }
    private void OrderStatus(object obj, OrderProcessing.OrderProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.totalCount > 0)
           bw.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(((double)e.currentCount / (double)e.totalCount) * 100),e.message);
    }
```

This in my `OrderProcessing` class

```
 public event EventHandler<OrderProgressEventArgs> OnOrderProgress;
 public class OrderProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int currentCount;
        public int totalCount;
        public string message;

        public OrderProgressEventArgs(int c, int t, string m)
        {
            currentCount = c;
            totalCount = t;
            message = m;
        }
    }

 protected virtual void OnOrderProgressChanged(OrderProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<OrderProgressEventArgs> handler = OnOrderProgress;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
        }
 public abstract List<MasterSalesOrder> CreateOrders(List<BrandItem> BrandItems = null, List<BrandItemMasterCustomer> BrandItemMasterCustomers = null);
```

and then I can use it in my child class `OrderProcessingFile` like so

```
 public override List<MasterSalesOrder> CreateOrders(List<BrandItem> BrandItems = null, List<BrandItemMasterCustomer> BrandItemMasterCustomers = null)
    {
        //Do some Stuff
        OnOrderProgressChanged(new OrderProgressEventArgs(count, totalItems, "Extracting"));
    }
```

and everything is working like a charm. Sorry for the utterly confusing question and the apparent huge gap of knowledge I have/had, but hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you create a thread safe singleton progress manager. Then have each of the background workers contact it with updates. The progress manager will use a [DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx) (which runs on the GUI thread) to update the GUI appropriately.

Raw example:

```
public static class StatusReportManager
{
   // Standard singleton code to create the manager and access it.
   // Start/create the dispatch time as well.

   private static DispatcherTimer Timer { get; set; } 

   private static object _syncObject = new object();

   public static void ReportStatus(...) 
   {
      lock (_syncObject)
      {
         // Process any states and set instance properties for reading
         // by the timer operation.    
      }        
   }

   private void ShowStatus() // Used by the dispatch timer
   {
        lock (_syncObject)
        {
           // Do any updates to the GUI in here from current state.
        }
   }
}
```